# Issue in installing new symfony project

Tags: php, symfony, xampp, ubuntu-14.04, phar

I am new to symfony and trying to creating project using symfony installer. I am following steps provided in [symfony setup](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html). My operating system is ubuntu 14.04 and using lampp to run project and manage database.
As steps suggested, I installed installer properly and running command to create new project. But this command throwing this error.
**Error:**[image].
I have searched for this issue and found solution to check if php have PHAR extension installed and enabled.[image]
 But, I had checked in phpinfo and extension is installed. My php version is 7.0.18.
So, Help me with this installation and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you don't have [ctype extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ctype.php) enabled. Check your `phpinfo()` for `ctype` section.

Comment: I checked in phpinfo. It is enabled.

Comment: Check it in console (not a browser), because PHP has a different configuration for browser and CLI.

Comment: After lot's of time investing, I found that phpinfo showing me lists of extension required for symfony installation is different from CLI and It is taking extenions from CLI. So after installing all extension, I finally able to install symfony. Thanks a lot!.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like php configuration problem  to me,  but

did you try with  clean composer installation  ?

```
 composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition ihomeseek
```

Comment: Yes, I tried installing with composer as well and this process throwing different type of error.  Problem 1
    - Installation request for doctrine/orm v2.5.6 -> satisfiable by doctrine/orm[v2.5.6].
    - doctrine/orm v2.5.6 requires ext-pdo * -> the requested PHP extension pdo is missing from your system.

Comment: Looks like you're missing a few basic extensions in your PHP.

Comment: you have  some  basic php  configuration without extensions